# Titanium settings to distribute an android app

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I have a doubt with the Android SDK setting in the menu for distribute an Android App in Titanium.

What **Android SDK Version** means?

- The minimum SDK Version?

Or

- I must create an APK for each Android
  Version?

If choose **Android 4.3 [x86]** the resultimg APK will work for the older android devices like 2.3.3 too?
And viceversa?

Answer (score 0):

The min sdk tells which would be the oldest version of android that it supports means if we give minSdk version 2.3.3 then it should work for all above and specific versions

Thanks